# Try to run a sample code but got "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a sample code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
and it is about parameter pack:
[image]

Then I tried to run the code in VSCode and here's the code snippet:

```
// template<typename U, typename... Ts>    // OK: can deduce U
// struct valid;
// template<typename... Ts, typename U> // Error: Ts... not at the end
// struct Invalid;
 
template<typename... Ts, typename U, typename=void>
void valid(U, Ts...);    // OK: can deduce U

int main() {
    valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3);     // OK: deduces U as double, Ts as {int, int, int}
    // void valid(Ts..., U); // Can't be used: Ts... is a non-deduced context in this position
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this using g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 I got erros:

c:/program files (x86)/mingw-w64/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-12.2.0-llvm-14.0.6-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\86189\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmLsbGr.o:test7.cpp:(.text+0x2b): **undefined reference to `void valid<int, int, int, double, void>(double, int, int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Not sure what is the problem.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11` is building a program. Compiling is `g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++11`. The examples show the C++ syntax, i.e. compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++ test.cpp -std=c++11` builds a program. Compiling is `g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++11`. The examples there demonstrate valid and invalid C++ code not caring  about linkage for shortness.

Answer (score 1):

`valid` is a declaration without an implementation, so the linker requires it to be implemented somewhere, so that calling it in `main` makes sense.

You can use `gcc`'s `-c` flag to preprocess, compile, and assemble without linking.

Comment: Thanks. BTW may I know what is the purpose of "typename=void" here? can compiler deduce it from "void valid()" which requires the function returns void?

Comment: I'm not sure, feel free to ask that as a new question.